# What is "|="statement mean in python?

Tags: python

what is "|="statement mean? This Code is just creat maze, and this is my first time to see this |= statement
i'm stack in here please help me

```
width = 10
height = 8
grid = ["23" * 89 for i in xrange(height)]

N, S, E, W = 1, 2, 4, 8
HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL = 0, 1

def divide(grid, mx, my, ax, ay):
    dx = ax - mx
    dy = ay - my
    if dx < 2 or dy < 2:

       if dx > 1:
          y = my
          for x in xrange(mx, ax-1):
              grid[y][x] |= E
              grid[y][x+1] |= W
```

what is |= mean?

Comment: mx = 0, my = 0 ax = width, ay = height

Answer (score 1):

The `|` symbol, and by extension `|=` is a bitwise OR.  This applies OR logic to the underlying bits.  For example:

```
00001001
00011000
-------- |
00011001
```

So `9 | 24 = 25`

Comment: Thanks for your explain!! But i need how "grid[y][x] |= E" work.

Comment: Exact same thing.